# FullCalendar: how to get data from db and show in events (as a json feed)

Tags: json, ajax, events, continuous-integration, fullcalendar

I am a newbie to fullcalendar and ajax. I have difficulty in fetching data from the database and those data should be shown up in my fullcalendar. 
    I have tried a code to do the same. but i am not able to get data through ajax as a json feed.
    So far i am getting data from the database through codeigniter MVC. but i 
    coulnt pass data to the fullcalendar event.

```
 The following is my view file: calendar.php


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>/common/calendar/show_holidays",
    type: 'POST', // Send post data
    data: 'type=fetch',
    async: true,
    success: function(s){
          freshevents = s;//alert(s);
    } 
});

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', JSON.parse(freshevents));

    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //events: JSON.parse(json_events),
        //events: [{"id":"14","title":"New Event","start":"2015-01-24T16:00:00+04:00","allDay":false}],
        utc: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, 
        events: {

        }

    });

   });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to parse `SQL` resultset to `JSON`, you can do that with the next `PHP` functions:

Connect to DB function:

```
function connectDB(){
   $con = mysqli_connect("HOST", "USER", "PASS", "DB");
    if($con){
        echo 'OK';
    }else{
        echo 'KO';
    }   
    return $con;
}
```

Function to disconnect from DB:

```
function disconnectDB($con){
    $close = mysqli_close($con);

    if($close){
        //echo 'OK';
    }else{
        //echo 'KO';
    }   
    return $close;
}
```

Function to get JSON parse from one resultset:

```
function getArraySQL(){
    $conexion = connectDB();
    //generate SQL query
    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT title,color,start FROM events")) die();

    $rawdata = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $title=$row['title'];
        $color=$row['color'];
        $start=$row['start'];

        $rawdata[] = array('title'=> $title, 'color'=> $color, 'start'=> $start);
    }
    disconnectDB($conexion);
    //Parse to JSON and return
    $rawdata=json_encode($rawdata);
    return $rawdata;
}
```

After this step, you can include `JSON` returned into your `events` calendar script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek'
        },
        events: <?php 
        $result = array();
        $result=getArraySQL();
        if(isset($result)){
            echo $result;
        }
        ?>,
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
        element.click(function() {
            alert(event.title);
        });
    }
    });

});
```

Hope this can help you.